# Hide a div when click outside of div when i have a script that changes what div is displayed depending on device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

New to JS and coding in general. My website is [www.sakenmusic.com](http://www.sakenmusic.com) if you need to look at the html. I want the navdemo menu to close when the user taps one of the buttons or taps out of the navdemo menu. The site is responsive and toggles between a navbar and navdemo with the js below:

```
// Used to toggle the menu on small screens when clicking on the menu button
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("navDemo");
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
  } else {
    x.className = x.className.replace("w3-show", "");
  }
}
```

What's the best way of going about this, collapse navDemo through js? 
Thanks

Comment: Why not just follow [the advices](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and create a **minimal** example? Of course we need the HTML. Please use the code button `<>` from the editor and create a **minimal** example.

Comment: Have a look [at the `classList` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). It will add and remove class names from elements a bit more elegantly.